# Resources for studying gomoku

Tags: gomoku

Are there any online resources for studying gomoku? I am a beginner and I'd be interested to learn the fundamentals.

A google search on terms such as "gomoku strategy" or "gomoku tutorial" didn't return any relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching for "gomoku", search for "renju tutorial" and you find this useful site:

http://renju.net/study/advanced.php

Comment: gomoku and renju has similar origin and basic ideas, however the differences are significant and hence are different games

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice overview of the game on Wikipedia along with a rules and variations section. Hope this helps.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomoku

Comment: thanks for the link, unfortunately it doesn't offer much beyond the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played Gomoku before, but this is a solved game, as shown by Victor Allis. Gomoku is a sure win for the first player.

When I say solved, it has been solved for AI (similar to draughts/checkers), but I would suggest you check out the guidelines in Allis' paper.

[L. Victor Allis, H. J. van den Herik, M. P. H. Huntjens. Go-Moku and Threat-Space Search](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~awojna/SID/referaty/Go-Moku.pdf)

Comment: Interesting paper, although not relevant as a study guide.